# FourSquare request returns null string in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, json, asihttprequest, foursquare

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to tap into the FourSquare API in my iOS app. However, when I try to print the JSON string that I expect to be returned to me, I am getting "null". If I navigate to the same request URL in a browser, I get a whole slew of JSON. Here is my code...

```
- (void)fetchFoursquareLocationsUsingLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
// First, let's build our request
CLLocationDegrees latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
NSString *foursquareURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%0.6f,%0.6f&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20120103", 
                                 latitude,
                                 longitude,
                                 FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID, 
                                 FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:foursquareURLString]];
self.foursquareData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

request.delegate = self;
[request startAsynchronous];
}

#pragma mark - ASIHTTPRequest Delegate
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[self.foursquareData appendData:data];

}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
NSString *jsonCheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.foursquareData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonCheck);
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to @Kamarshad's SO post [How to get Venues list Using FourSquare Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783027/how-to-get-venues-list-using-foursquare-api/9325717#9325717), I was able to get valid JSON back. The difference being I made the request asynchronously such that

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:foursquareURLString]];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:queue 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    //
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong...%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
    }
}];
```

What is it about the ASIHTTPRequest that keeps a valid response from coming back??

Answer (score 0):

This is happenning beacuse your are not passing the the `V(date)` value correctly at the time of Request you just pass the static(old) which may not work after that date.
You will have to pass the Updated(current) `V(date)` in URL String i.e `V` should be the CurrentDate in which you are makingRequest to FourSquare.

Try Below Code and Use again.

**Update:** One Thing More You should pass some thing to be search
Because in your Request you are not passing any search query

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
//dateString it;s used for being UpTodate for API request
NSString* rest=@"street"
// To be Search
```

**MakeRequest As Below and Rest of The Code will be same as you used.**

```
NSString *foursquareURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%0.6f,%0.6f&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@&query=%@", 
                             latitude,
                             longitude,
                             FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID, 
                             FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET,dateString,rest];
//Convert the Special characters into escapes. 

 foursquareURLString =[foursquareURLString  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:foursquareURLString]];
 //Rest will be same
```

[For More Detail About the FourSquare API endpoints go Through This Link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)

I Hope It'll give you the Correct Result Instead of the `Null` !!!!!!!.

Comment: I was hard coding yesterday's date (20120103) just to try and get a valid response. As I said before, I would get back JSON if I used the exact same URL in a web browser, but NULL in my app. Replacing the hard-coded date with a current date formatted from [NSDate date] still returns NULL.

Comment: @jmstone have u used right  Date Formate `NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate]'...?

Comment: @jmstone check you are getting the URL,i have updated the above ANswer.Because  URL string may have some Special character,these special Characters needs to convert into escapes.When hit that URl string(having Special Character),Browser have auto filling of Escapes corresponding specials characters

Comment: I've confirmed that already. What's more, I have copied the URL from my browser that produces valid JSON and pasted it directly into the URL string (replacing the formatted string) and still get NULL back. I'm thinking perhaps it is either a) The request has to go through a webView of some sort, or b) getting the data back and creating a UTF8String from that data is not the correct approach.

Comment: Tried that one last night :) Still nothing coming back. I have tried both NSString *jsonCheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.foursquareData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithData:self.foursquareData];

Comment: @jmstone see this answer at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783027/how-to-get-venues-list-using-foursquare-api/9325717#9325717 ,at this link i am just making the synchronous request to FourSquare API.you may also use synchronous Request instead of making ASIHTTPRequest .

Comment: Also, I AM getting data back from the request. So it's not like the data I am trying to pass is null to begin with or anything.

Comment: you doing wrong..just see your code NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithData:self.foursquareData]; self.foursquareData is totally wrong you are passing the NSData to string accepting method you need to pass jsonCheck .please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783027/how-to-get-venues-list-using-foursquare-api/9325717#9325717

Comment: So I don't know why using ASIHTTPRequest vs your method didn't work, but using the SO link you provided, this seems to be working.